Baidu Maps route planner doesn't show trains between Shanghai and Wuxi
I'm planning a day trip from Shanghai to Wuxi by train. The interesting thing is that train booking websites, such as Trip.com, show many direct trains (40 min only) between these cities but Baidu Maps route planner keeps suggesting me to take a bus (which will take 3.5 hours) and apparently doesn't know anything about the trains on this route.

Source: Trip.com


Source: Baidu Maps
Could you please tell me why Baidu Maps don't know about these trains? I checked some other destinations in China, and Baidu Maps display trains to them.
Anyway, do trains really go between Shanghai and Wuxi?

You're spot on about the train situation! There are tons of high-speed bullet trains zooming between Shanghai and Wuxi, taking just 40 minutes. Trust me, train websites like Trip.com are definitely onto something there.
Baidu Maps might be a bit bus-crazy for this route. It loves showing buses (which take like 3.5 hours for this trip, yikes!), and trains might not be the first thing on its mind. But don't worry, trains are absolutely the way to go for Shanghai to Wuxi. Here's the lowdown on other options:
BusTime required: about 3-4 hours
Sure it's cheaper, but you'll be on wheels for a loooong time.
TaxiTime required: about 2 hours
Fancy and convenient, but definitely pricier, especially for a longer trip like this.
So yeah, stick with the trains. Fast, convenient, and perfect for a day trip!

Can you add why the Baidu maps route planner does not include these trains? This is a good post but does not answer that part of the question.

There is probably some kind of Baidu algorithm to determine whether to even check trains based on distance and other proximity measures. The national trains are not integrated and there are two interfaces, one for metro/buses and another one for trains and flights. Chinese railway stations require security checks and the tickets usually have to be reserved beforehands, so many apps do not integrate the railway schedule directly within the regional public transport system (like Google maps). Some apps, like Gaode, can do some level of travel planning with both bus/metro and trains, but usually you'd still need to confirm if it is optimal yourself. It also happens that websites and apps can have different functions, e.g. for Baidu.
When in doubt, you can always check the official website https://www.12306.cn/en/index.html, the English version has improved a lot (even if there are still some bugs).
